# I am getting the error when using super in derived class

Tags: javascript

I am new to JS and was learning classes in JS. The problem I encountered is error: unknown: Unexpected token in this code:

```
class Car{

  run(){
    console.log('Run');
  }
}

class Chevy extends Car{
  constructor(){
  }

  super.run();// Here I have the error
}
```

Comment: move `super.run();` to constructor if you want to run it on object creation

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/super

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the classes body you can only have (1) property initializers, (2) constructors, (3) method declarations. You can't add arbitrary statements, e.g. a method call there. Move that call into the constructor to run it on construction, or move it into a method:

```
 class Chevy extends Car{
  constructor() {
   super.run();
  }
  method() {
    super.run();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
class Car{

  run(){
    console.log('Run');
  }
}

class Chevy extends Car{
  constructor(){
  }
  run(){
    super.run();
  }
}
```